# Red Gate Ants does not trace any methods in deployed code

Tags: c#, asp.net, profiling, red-gate-ants

I'm using this profiler (trial version) to track down some performance issues occured in a web application. Locally it works fine and I see methods in a call tree. I want it to work also on remote server, to collect a performance profile there.

So I deployed the website (debug configuration) to remote server, and checked that *.pdb files are also in /bin directory.
Then via remote desktop tried to do the same,i.e. attach to .NET process (w3wp). I checked the process ID so that it matches IIS pool. However, when started profiling, I don't see my methods, but `The profiler did not find any methods with the source code. To see all profiled methods, in Display Options below select "All methods"`.

I guess it happens when you attach to wrong app pool. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, this sounds like ANTS isn't able to find the correct PDBs. The PDBs should be in the same folder as any DLLs, and (apart from file extension) should have the same name. The PDBs also need to exactly match the version of the assemblies being profiled. There's more information at http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/APP9/Troubleshooting+PDB+problems.

Failing that, you could change the "Methods with source" drop-down to "All methods" just above the call tree. This will show you timing information for all methods regardless of whether you have PDBs available, but won't then show you source code or line-level timings. Alternatively their support team can probably help.